# Don't get the correct lasso MSE

Tags: regression, matlab, lasso-regression

I'm new with regressions and I wrote a very simple code in matlab that uses lasso function just to see if I understand how lasso's MSE is calculated. But I get mse that is different than lasso's output. I'm probably missing something and I'd appreciate if anyone here can tell me where I'm wrong. For calculating the MSE I used the following formula from this link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso.html
[image]

And here's the matlab code that I wrote:

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

% Checking lasso MSE from this link:
% https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso.html

n = 10;
p = 3;
X = 20*rand(n,p);
min_val = -20;
max_val = 20;  
y = min_val + (max_val - min_val)*rand(n,1);

lambda_vals = [0.2, 0.8, 1, 1.5];
[beta_vectors , FitInfo] = lasso(X, y, 'Lambda', lambda_vals);

eps = 10^-10;
num_of_lambda_vals = length(lambda_vals);
for i=1:num_of_lambda_vals 
    current_calculated_mse = sum((y - FitInfo.Intercept(i) - X*beta_vectors(:,i)).^2)/(2*n) +...
        lambda_vals(i)*sum(abs(beta_vectors(:,i)));    
    current_mse = FitInfo.MSE(i);

    fprintf('current_calculated_mse = %f\n',current_calculated_mse);
    fprintf('current_mse = %f\n',current_mse);
    sqr_diff_mses = (current_calculated_mse-current_mse)^2;
    if (sqr_diff_mses > eps)
        fprintf('The calculated MSE is wrong!\n');
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

If you run the code it will print that the calculate MSE is wrong.
Can anybody tell what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you start by tidying your code and removing the bunch of unnecesarily long operations you do. E.g. Beta_0 does not need to be repmat'ed, or you do not need `temp`, you can directly compute the square root in the same line. Your for loop should not be longer than 5 or 6 lines, right now it only makes it way harder to follow.

Comment: I updated the code and made it shorter. The loop is only a few lines now (most of them fprintf lines).

Comment: Are you sure that your implementation of `x^{T}*beta` is correct? I am not experienced with Lasso, but I feel like that part is not quite right (you do not seem to transpose X)

Comment: I'm not sure of anything. That's why I posted here. if I transpose X then I won't be able to multiply it with beta. I don't know why the transpose sign in the formula but I needed to ignore it otherwise I wouldn't be able to do the calculations.

Comment: @David as I mention in my answer: Your code is good, you are just using the wrong equation!

Comment: Yes I just read your reply and realized I used the wrong equation. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just using the wrong equation

When you want to propose a minimization problem, then you add regularization and other terms to a function to minimize, and in your case, it's the equation you shared.

However, when you want to validate your results, you are only interested in knowing how different your solution applied to the model compared to the real data. This means that when you compute the error (MSE in this case), you just need:

[image]

where  your solution applied to the model is

[image]

In short: Change `current_calculated_mse` to

```
current_calculated_mse = sum((y - FitInfo.Intercept(i) - X*beta_vectors(:,i)).^2)/(n);
```

Outputs:

```
current_calculated_mse = 116.748997
current_mse = 116.748997

current_calculated_mse = 122.421290
current_mse = 122.421290

current_calculated_mse = 125.824726
current_mse = 125.824726

current_calculated_mse = 137.641287
current_mse = 137.641287
```

---

Why not use the minimizing equation for the error? It makes sense if we are minimizing that!

Yes! And no. You propose a minimizing equation to steer a solution with some desired properties, in the case of Lasso, you want as many of the beta values to be zero. But that does not mean that your solution is any good.

You could as well have minimized an equation that said `argmin ( beta*x-y )*0+(1-beta)`. This equation, solved, will have `beta=1` as a perfect minimizer, but does that mean that your solution is perfect? No, not at all! You just chose a bad fucntion to minimize. You want the beta that fits the real data (`y`) better. In your case is the same, as you are using a varying set of lambdas. You can see in the solutions that your big lambdas solve the equation too, but the solutions fit the real data worse. You are doing this to chose the best lambda.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense since the goal is eventually to be as closest as possible to y_i samples. Indeed I used the wrong equation. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Can you explain why in Lasso I want as many of beta values to be zero?

Comment: @David You are minimizing 2 things with that equation: a) the 2 norm (left part of the equation) to make your model as close as possible to `y` and b) the 1 norm of beta, i.e. you want beta to have  the smallest values possible. Smallest value is zero (because you are doing `abs()`). Its what lasso does, it has been designed for this specifically. Its quite useful in a lot of aplications

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Is ridge doing the same thing (trying to have as many of beta values to be zero)? It's trying to minimize 2 norm of beta instead of 1 norm of beta (square instead of abs). or does it have a different goal? (I can't figure out the goal difference between them).

Comment: @David no, ridge is not minimizing the 2 norm of beta, its minimizing the 2 norm of y-beta_0-x*beta.